# Can't connect SonarQube to LDAP directory for user mapping

Tags: ldap, sonarqube

I'm trying to set up the user mapping on SonarQube (Latest) so it can fetch the organizational structure from LDAP.

I already installed the LDAP plugin on Sonar (1.5.1), and created a minimal configuration to connect the two:

```
# General Configuration
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
ldap.url=ldap://ldap:389

# User Mapping
ldap.user.baseDn=ou=users,ou=udd,dc=example,dc=com
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid={uid}))
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn
ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail
```

All my users are under the example.com domain:

[image: LDAP Structure]

But then, as I try to login to Sonar using the LDAP entries I get the following error on the logs:

```
Error from external users provider: exception Java::OrgSonarApiUtils::SonarException: Unable to retrieve details for user dev1 in <default>
```

Which is pretty frustrating, since all those properties are configured on the configuration file above.

Any ideas about the source of this issue?

EDIT:

I found this when I increased the log depth to DEBUG:

```
2016.01.25 05:54:27 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.LdapContextFactory] Initializing LDAP context {java.naming.provider.url=ldap://ldap:389, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory, com.sun.jndi.ld
ap.connect.pool=true, java.naming.security.authentication=simple, java.naming.referral=follow}
2016.01.25 05:54:27 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.LdapUsersProvider] integer expected inside {}: (&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid={uid}))
javax.naming.directory.InvalidSearchFilterException: integer expected inside {}: (&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid={uid}))
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.dir.SearchFilter.format(SearchFilter.java:602) ~[na:1.7.0_95]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(LdapCtx.java:1785) ~[na:1.7.0_95]
...
```

I don't see why is an integer supposed to be expected between the {}'s, and that doesn't make much sense compared to my LDAP structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set `ldap.user.request` to `(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid={login})` (instead of using `(uid={uid})`).

## Details:

The LDAP Plugin does not recognise `{uid}` and therefore doesn't know what to do with it. It then passes it to the LDAP `javax.naming` API, which chokes on this. This behaviour is made explicit at SonarQube startup (logs in my case):

> INFO  web[o.s.p.l.LdapSettingsManager]  User mapping: LdapUserMapping{baseDn=cn=employees,dc=example,dc=org, request=(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)**(uid={uid}))**, realNameAttribute=cn, emailAttribute=mail}

Using `{login}` instead (keyword shown in the [documented default values](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin)) will let the LDAP Plugin build a well-formed request with a **{0}**:

> INFO  web[o.s.p.l.LdapSettingsManager]  User mapping: LdapUserMapping{baseDn=cn=employees,dc=example,dc=org, request=(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)**(uid={0}))**, realNameAttribute=cn, emailAttribute=mail}

The `javax.naming` API will then replace this `{0}` by a parameter which SonarQube will set to the actual username value you fill in the login form.

Comment: for me {uid} did not work, but {login}, as per documentation: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/delegated-auth/